# How to display selectedlist selected value by id?

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, selectedvalue, displayfor

I have Category model

```
public class Category
{
    //[PlaceHolder("Select file")]
    //[UmbracoRequired("Form.Label.Import.SelectFile")]
    //[UmbracoDisplay("Form.Label.Import.SelectFile")]
    //[Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and a list of categories created in my controller

```
List<Category> items = new List<Category>();
```

Category list should be used in the (strongly typed) view where I have a foreach loop displaying another model Course eg.

```
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Students)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdmissionInfo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryId)
        </td>
```

So instead of

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryId)
```

it should display a Name property of the Category type depending on the CategoryId value of Course model

```
SelectList categories = new SelectList((IEnumerable<MvcImport.Models.Category>)ViewData["categories"], "Id", "Name", item.CategoryId);
```

Eg.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(categories.Where(m => m.Id == item.CategoryId).FirstOrDefault())
```

But that last line does not work.

Not sure how to call just the value.
(I DO NOT want to display a dropdown, just the selected value)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => categories.First(m => m.Id == item.CategoryId).Name)
```

or more safely (formatted for readability) :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => categories.Where(m => m.Id == item.CategoryId)
                                        .Select(m => m.Name)
                                        .FirstOrDefault())
```

Comment: Thanks @har07 I'm getting `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'` for the line m.Id == item.CategoryId for both examples (both Category.Id and Course.CategoryId are integers of course. My view is of type `@model IEnumerable<MvcImport.Models.Course>`

Comment: I assumed that `categories` is of type `IEnumerable<Category>`, didn't notice that you declared it as `SelectList`. Try : `var categories = (IEnumerable<SOMvcApplication.Models.Category>) ViewData["categories"];`

Comment: Fantastic @har07! This works `var categories = (IEnumerable<MvcImport.Models.Category>)ViewData["categories"];` with `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => categories.First(m => m.Id == item.CategoryId).Name)`

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x =>item.RequestTypeID, new SelectList(ViewBag.RequestTypes, "Value", "Text", item.RequestTypeID))
```